# lxpanel volume control not visible plus no sound

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, volume-control

I installed Lubuntu on my laptop, and it is working extremely well. However, I cannot figure out how to add applets to the panel. In particular, I cannot add volume control, so I cannot figure out how to change my volume (which is currently muted).

Also, my function keys no longer work (which is not surprising). How can I make it so that I have control over the volume using the panel applet and my function keys?

Thanks for any replies.

Update: After testing this out with other applets, I found the problem is that volume control is not visible. How can I make it visible?

Update: I played with alsamixer and found I have no sound. How can I fix this?

Update: Here is the output of `pulseaudio`

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="29" name="platform-thinkpad_acpi" card_name="alsa_card.platform-thinkpad_acpi" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix the problem. For anyone else who has this problem: be sure to change the default volume card. Here is how you can do that:

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to start LXTerm
2. Type `sudo leafpad /etc/asound.conf`
3. Type <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Copy and paste

`defaults.ctl.card 2`

`defaults.pcm.card 2`

`defaults.timer.card 2`

into the file.

Change the number 2 to the sound card you want to use, then save the file and restart your computer.